# Bundle i18n json files with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, i18next

I work with a React project and I'm adding multilingual support via i18next. For every component, I have a separate `locale` folder with multiple json files, one per language.

I'm trying to package all these files into a single `locales.json` file and use it to configure i18next. I've found a Webpack plugin ([merge-jsons-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/tettusud/merge-jsons-webpack-plugin)) that does the packaging work exactly how I want it, it creates the output file in the build folder, but then I don't know how to use the result.

Here's the `plugins` section of my Webpack config:

```
new MergeJsonWebpackPlugin({
  output: {
    groupBy: [
      {
        pattern: 'app/**/locales/*.json',
        fileName: 'locales.json',
      },
    ],
  },
})
```

How do I refer to the build artefact in my code? How can I import locales.json?
Am I missing the point with Webpack here? If so, what's the purpose of the aforementioned plugin?

Comment: Why don’t you load your json via http call then? Since you’re unable to require it in your bundle code in case of using plugin I guess

Comment: The file shows up in the build folder, so it should work fine in production, but it doesn't seem to work in development mode (react-boilerplate).

Comment: Not sure what do you really need?

Comment: I have some json files, I want to merge them into one and then use the resulting object to configure i18next. I would like to do the merge within Webpack, because it makes sense to me to do it as a pre-build step, but then I don't know how to refer the output from my code. I need to know if this is possible, if it makes sense and, if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These threads appear to address the problems you might be having:

1. [How to use Webpack to combine JSON files from all subdirectories into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000173/how-to-use-webpack-to-combine-json-files-from-all-subdirectories-into-one#40022630)
2. [Webpack Plugin: run command after assets are written to file system
   #6159](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6159)

To summarize, I'll quote from [GJK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277669/gjk) in the first thread:

> "webpack is not really suited for the use case you have."

However, you can accomplish your goal of both merging and injecting at the compilation and bundling stages using the approach suggested below.

Use Webpack's [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to assign a value (a serialized JSON object) to a global variable. This global variable can then be assigned to the i18next `resources` property to initialize translations.

Rather than using *merge-jsons-webpack-plugin* to create a merged file, you could create a merged JSON object (not a file) using:

1. [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob),
2. [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options), and
3. [deepmerge-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge-json).

The search patterns you are currently using with *merge-jsons-webpack-plugin* should work with glob, but might require a few adjustments. deepmerge-json is quite flexible and should be able to accommodate the structure of your .json translation files.

You can download, install, build and test a simple demonstration that you can update for your purposes from this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/kofeigen/3f41c1fc5a21b39ad8ca5309bc0fde1d).

Comment: I agree with you (and GJK) that this is not the best use for webpack. I came into this conclusion after testing different solutions, none of them being satisfying enough. Thanks for your thorough answer!

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. Would you be able to briefly share the solution that worked for you?

Comment: I just created a small script that loops through a given path pattern with glob, merges all the json objects into one and saves the result in a file. The script is called every time we make changes to the language files and before any build.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Webpack's [`Dynamic expressions in import()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import) which allows you to import all files by some pattern without using a plugin.

```js
// imagine we had a method to get language from cookies or other storage
const language = detectVisitorLanguage();
import(`./locale/${language}.json`).then(module => {
  // do something with the translations
});
```